# building first mobile app using Phgonegap

Tags: cordova

I have a job portal and  I'm going to build a job app that will run on various OS devices using Phonegap.I have tried in Android Studio there when run  we select the emulator then it converts into apk. My question is will the phonegap will convert the html file  into different OS exe file??

Answer (score 0):

When you build application by Phonegap, it's will run as your application view on a webview, it's unable to convert .html file into other type of file. For e.x: You could see .java file in Android Studio, it will call to .html file on `asset` folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse  Mr Neo

Answer (score 0):

You don't convert, you build the apps.
To build an app for a specific OS you have to have the development environment of the OS you want it to have to.
For Android it's the Android SDK with Android Studio.
For iOS/OSX it's XCode which is only available on a OSX Computer (f.e. Macbook, iMac, ...)
For Windows you need the Windows Phone SDK.

More information about this you'll find on the [Platform Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides) in the Phonegap documentation

Comment: dat means i have to add various sdk for different os  along with phonegap.?can u provide me any info regarding how in backened it works

Comment: What do you mean with backend?